# android: where is the android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED?

Tags: android

I'm writing an App that needs to receive sms, everyone use "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION" intent action in their code, but it looks like API level 17 doesn't support it anymore! 
where it is now? I also didn't find SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION in "android.telephony" class!
please someone tell me, I'm totally confused. should I use older APIs?

Comment: what makes you think its deprecated?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Telephony class does not have a documented API until API 19 (4.4 - KitKat). The absence of the class does not mean what you are trying to do does not work. You need to request this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
```

And if you register your receiver in your manifest it will look something like this:

```
    <receiver android:name=".SmsIntentReceiver">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

From the android.provider.Telephony AOSP:

```
public static final String SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION = "android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED";
```

Here is a grepcode.com reference to the source:

http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.2_r1/android/provider/Telephony.java/?v=source

Notice the "@hide" just before the class declaration - it is there, but not exposed to devs. That is why it is not recognized in the ADT.

Answer (score 6):

We need to read this document.

[Android Developers Blog - Getting Your SMS Apps Ready for KitKat](http://android-developers.blogspot.kr/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html)

> Beginning with Android 4.4, **you should stop listening for the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast**, which you can do at runtime by checking the platform version then disabling your broadcast receiver for SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION with PackageManager.setComponentEnabledSetting(). However, you can continue listening for that broadcast if your app needs only to read special SMS messages, such as to perform phone number verification. Note that—beginning with Android 4.4—any attempt by your app to abort the SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION broadcast will be ignored so all apps interested have the chance to receive it.

I think we must to prepare for KitKat. It's a bothering thing. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION` in your code.

Below is my working code:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION)) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
        }
    }
}
```

You have to import `import android.provider.Telephony;`

Answer (score 0):

**`android.telephony`** class provides information about phones states which is introduced in api level 1. For more details please read this [android.telephony](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/package-summary.html)

**`android.telephony.SmsManager`** is for fetching the information of message from device inbox. You can look about it here [telephony.SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html)

There is no indication that they are deprecated in api level 17.

Comment: thanks for the info. I said android.provider.telephony is replaced, and telephony.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION is gone! I want to know where can I find it